# C#: Monitor.Pulse() doesn't work

Tags: c#, multithreading, pulse

I had a problem which I reduced to this minimal test-case, and still I don't understand why doesn't it work properly. The code here is simple: the parent thread acquires a lock, then launch a child, next frees the lock by starting await on it. Then the child thread that were locked on the same lock proceeds, frees the parent, next sleeps for five seconds.

```
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Object waitForThrToStart = new Object();
            lock (waitForThrToStart)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    lock (waitForThrToStart)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("2. Child: free the parent");
                        Monitor.Pulse(waitForThrToStart);
                        Debug.WriteLine("3. Child: pulsed ☺ Now sleep");
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        Debug.WriteLine("5. Child: time out");
                    }
                }).Start();
                Debug.WriteLine("1. Parent: waiting");
                Monitor.Wait(waitForThrToStart);
                Debug.WriteLine("4. Parent: awoke, exiting now");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is fine except that… it doesn't work. The parent freed only after five seconds, when the child exited, you may see it in output:

```
1. Parent: waiting
2. Child: free the parent
3. Child: pulsed ☺ Now sleep
5. Child: time out
4. Parent: awoke, exiting now
```

I did even try to use `Monitor.PulseAll()`, that didn't change anything. Also I thought perhaps for some weird reason the child got a copy of the Object, thus they're work on different variables. But I disproved it by setting a `Sleep()` call in parent — the child surely waited for the lock.

What is this, is that a bug? Is there any workaround?

Comment: "Is there any workaround?" - don't use `Pulse`/`Wait`. Whatever *problem* you're trying to solve, there's almost certainly a better way to address it and usually it'll be at a higher level that thread synchronization primitives.

Comment: And this is the [documented behaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): "When the thread that invoked `Pulse` **releases the lock**, the next thread in the ready queue (which is not necessarily the thread that was pulsed) acquires the lock." (My emphasis)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well, in real code i have a thread that lauches a number of other threads which doing some work. Next the parent thread should wait for some time until one of a childs would signal, either just go away if time out. I have no idea how to make this work another way.

Comment: That sounds more like you want an event - there are a number of these such as `ManualResetEvent`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wow, that's indeed seems to be what I wanted. I tried to search for something like *«C# thread safe boolean»*, and etc. but didn't managed to find anything. Thank you, it is indeed simplifies the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pulsing the monitor in child, but you've also got it locked. The `Wait` will only return once you've released the lock in the child thread, at which point it will need to reacquire the lock before returning.

Comment: Indeed, that worked! It was again neither obvious, nor even logical; I never tire to wonder the .net API.